# mysql last 5 records in count status

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, count, sql-order-by

booking table

```
id    status
1     booked
1     booked
3     cancelled
2     cancelled
2     booked
1     cancelled
1     cancelled
1     booked
```

```
select id, count(status) as tot_cancel 
from tbl_booking 
where id=1 and status='cancelled';
```

result will be

```
id    tot_cancel
1     2
```

BUT I NEED last 5 records of user id = 1 and cancelled count not total table record cancelled

Comment: Better give an example of the results you want

Comment: There is NO any ordering data which allows to understand what records are LAST.

Comment: @airmax . . . You should probably ask a *new* question.  Your question does not define "last" -- SQL tables represent *unordered* sets, so there is no "last" unless a column defines the ordering.  In addition, you should show the result set you want.

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you want the count of cancelled records over the last 5 records of user 1. It is possibe, but you need a column that defines the ordering of the rows, so it is unambiguous which records are *last*.

Assuming that such column exists in your table and is called `ordering_id`, you can do:

```
select sum(status = 'cancelled') no_cancelled
from (select status from mytable where id = 1 order by ordering_id desc limit 5) t
```

Comment: 1 errors were found during analysis.

Variable name was expected. (near "?" at position 110)

SQL query: Documentation

SELECT sum(status='cancelled') no_cancelled FROM (SELECT status from `qry_booking` WHERE id='3' order by ? limit 5 )

Comment: @airmax: in my initial answer, `?` represented the *ordering column*, which I mentionned in my answer. I updated the query in between to make it more explicit (but you still need an ordering column though).

Comment: why need to put t in end reason please

Comment: @airmax: that's an alias for the subquery - it is important and mandatory.

Answer (score 0):

You can do conditional aggregation with `limit` clause :

```
select 1 as id, sum(status = 'cancelled')
from table t
where id = 1
order by ? -- use ordering column instead ?
limit 5;
```

You can use correlated subquery for all `id`s :

```
select t.id, sum(t.status = 'cancelled')
from table t
where t.? in (select t1.? 
              from table t1 
              where t1.id = t.id 
              order by t1.? 
              limit 5
             )
group by t.id;
```